# How to stringify object with read only properties?

Tags: typescript

The following code:

```
class A {
    get p1(): number {
        return 1;
    }

    get p2(): number {
        return 2;
    }
}

const a = new A();

console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
```

Produces the following output:

```
{}
```

Is there a way to get something like the following?:

```
{
   "p1": 1,
   "p2": 2
}
```

Comment: You'd have to make those getters both instance-own and enumerable, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WGAG9N), or customize the `toJSON` method like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wgQGMm).  See the answers to the linked questions for more info